# JpaQueryException - play framework

Tags: playframework

I get this message when i deploy my code in dev mode onto a staging 
server

```
JPAQueryException occured : Error while executing query select s from  from something s where enabled = 0: Unknown column
```

but no issues running code from my machine.

Comment: Are you able to provide a code snippet that shows what generated the sql that is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
I had previously deployed my war to a windows machine with tomcat. when deploying new build I had only deleted my war file but not the unzipped folder which seemed to be causing the issue. once i deleted the war and the unzipped folder on my stage machine and then redployed my new war the error was no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the keyword `from` appears twice?

Comment: sorry that was me cutting out the actual query. Solved this.